# como usar Polymer Cli y PHP conjuntamente

Tags: php, javascript, polymer

Un saludo a todos.

Hace pocas semanas que empece a explorar, aprender y usar Polymer 3.x, me gusta mucho todo, pero tengo esta GRAN duda sobre como usar Polymer Cli durante el desarrollo, conjuntamente con Xampp/Apache/PHP para los ajax request.

Usando "polymer serve" mientras estoy desarrollando, ¿cómo "dirijo" los request de ajax hacia el Xampp/Apache/PHP que quiero usar durante desarrollo, pero tambien despues cuando pase a produccion?.

Probe metiendo todo en htdocs, pero no puedo obtener respuestas desde las rutinas en los .php

Agrego una aclaracion mas: si hago un build y pongo todo en htdoc si recibo correctamente las respuestas de los request. Pero mientras desarrollo, usando el polymer serve, ¿como hago andar los request hacia el PHP?

No se si queda mas o menos clara la pregunta. Gracias y espero que alguien pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas polymer serve no puedes usar PHP, o al menos yo nunca pude.

De todos modos, no es necesario usar Polymer CLI para usar Polymer. Aquí te dejo una adaptación que hice de Polymer para usarlo sin CLI, https://arismanwebs.es/docs/recursos-web/polymer-3/polymer-3-es6-compilado-para-web

Con esta adaptación de Polymer 3, puedes usarlo sin necesidad ni tan siquiera de compilarlo con polymer build y además tiene algunas funcionalidades extra además de la ventaja de no realizar cientos de peticiones al servidor.

Eso sí, está pensado para crear tus propios componentes, si quieres usar una APP desarrollada con Polymer, tan solo tendrás que buscar en los archivos de los componentes que te descargues a parte y cambiar las rutas de los imports que usan nombres de paquetes y orientarlos utilizando su ruta relativa o absoluta. Por ejemplo:

Cambia:

```
import "@polymer/polymer-element"
```

Por:

```
import "../../aw_polymer_3/polymer/polymer-element.js".
```

Igual tendrás que hacer si encuentras import hacia nombres de paquetes de webcomponentsjs.

Ten en cuenta que en esta adaptación de Polymer, todo lo que apunte a cualquier archivo dentro de la carpeta de Polymer tiene que ir redirigido a polymer-element.js ya que todo Polymer está dentro de ese archivo.a

Una vez modificada las rutas, no necesitarás ni el CLI ni compilar los componentes ya que hoy día todos los navegadores son compatibles con ES6, con añadir los polyfills para Edge te valdría y dentro de poco, cuando Edge se pase a Chromium ni tan siquiera necesitarás el uso de los polyfills.

Comment: hola, gracias. Luego de buscar un poco si pude usar. Se hace de esta forma:

`polymer serve --proxy-path services --proxy-target http://localhost/Polymer/3.x/prueba/services`

Todo iron-ajax url que dirijas a "services" o cualquier subdirectorio interior, te lo envia a (por ejemplo) `http://localhost/Polymer/3.x/prueba/services`